# ExpressionEngine - How to implement Ajax?

Tags: ajax, expressionengine

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588954/expression-engine-controllers) question has an answer that basically says to make template groups and templates act like controllers and output JSON like data.

Is this the correct way to do this in ExpressionEngine? or are there native, more "natural" way to do Ajax?

Comment: FYI: The EE focused SE site is now in public beta if you want to post future EE questions there: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach here likely depends on the data that you're working with. If you are looking to output JSON-formatted content from the core channel entries module then I'd recommend using Rob Sanchez's [ExpressionEngine JSON plugin](https://github.com/rsanchez/json).

If you're working with a custom-built module then you might as well extend that a little further and implement a JSON method. For example, if you have a Widgets module you could create a `json()` method within that and then utilise it within templates via `{exp:widgets:json var="foo"}`.